# Is there a way to make a function from a method inside a class

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I have a number class that has two methods in it:

```
    def digit_sum(self):
        """Returns the sum of all the digits"""
        str_num = str(self.num)
        ans = Number(0)
        for item in str_num:
            ans += Number(item)
        return ans

    def digit_product(self):
        """Returns the sum of all the digits"""
        str_num = str(self.num)
        ans = Number(1)
        for item in str_num:
            ans *= Number(item)
        return ans
```

I would like those methods to be accessible like functions, for example, I would type `x = digit_product(Number(54))`
Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Can you explain *why* this is desirable? These function/methods clearly have no meaning for non-`Number`s, so why not just do `Number(54).digit_product()`? This smells of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: Can you please include the rest of the `Number` class definition, namely the `__init__` and relevant attributes?

Comment: A reason I can imagine you might want to do this would be to pass as a parameter to a `map`, `sort`, or similar.  E.g. `numbers.sort(key=Number.digit_product)` to sort a list of Numbers according to their digit products.

Comment: Realistically, the argument doesn't need to be a `Number`; at that point, we're basically talking about an alternative constructor, accessed like `x = Number.digit_product(54)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already access the function as an attribute of the class, like this:

```
Number.digit_product(Number(54))
```

If you want to be able to access it as the name `digit_product` you could simply do:

```
digit_product = Number.digit_product
```

Comment: If it's going to be accessed as an attribute of the class, it should be decorated `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`

Comment: If you do that, you remove the ability to call it as an instance method as `instance.method()`.  It is not necessary to make it a static or class method to make it also be available as an attribute of the class.

Comment: @sabik: And in fact, in this specific case, using `staticmethod` or `classmethod` would be wrong; the `self` argument is being passed explicitly, rather than implicitly as in method call syntax, and failing to receive it (or trying to pass the class, followed by the instance as an argument) would break.

Comment: @sabik It's the value *bound* to `self`. For an *instance* method `bar`, `foo.bar()` and `type(foo).bar(foo)` are equivalent (ignoring inheritance). For a class method `bar`, `foo.bar()` and `type(foo).bar(type(foo))` are equivalent. For a static method `bar`, `foo.bar()` and `type(foo).bar()` are equivalent.

Comment: `self` is just a parameter name.  You can define a regular function with a parameter called `self` and it'll work just fine, and you can define a method where the first parameter is called something other than `self` (it will still be bound to the instance if you invoke it as an instance method).  You should not actually do either of these things because they're confusing, but it's important to understand that calling that parameter `self` is just a convention; the name `self` does not change the semantics of how calling the function works.

Comment: Note that `self` does not strictly need to be an instance of the class either -- every now and then it can be useful to do something like `MyClass.my_method(mock_instance)` in a test to exercise the logic in a method against a mock rather than an actual class instance.

Comment: As you say, "[y]ou should not actually do either of these things".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these methods are defined on `Number`, they're already functions; you can already do this by doing:

```
x = Number.digit_product(Number(54))
```

If you have some scenario where multiple classes might provide a method of the same name, but you only want to call the one associated with that class, you could write a simple wrapper:

```
def digit_product(x):
    return x.digit_product()
```

which will dispatch to the appropriate method while still allowing you to call it in top-level function syntax. If it gets more complicated (not all types have the same method, but you want it to work for all types), [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) allows you to specialize calls related to a specific type, while all non-specialized calls try the default code path, e.g.:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def digit_product(x):
    return x.digit_product()

@digit_product.register
def _(x: MyWeirdNumber):
    return x.my_weird_digit_product()
```